# How does the added regexp match work along with allowing Arbitrary Server?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Excuse if I am missing something, but how does differ from the original methods of involving a regexp in arbitrary servers? Are the preparations for a regexp match significantly different now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to version 4.4.0, there was only the directive `$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer']` which could be either true or false. 
When a system administrator set this to true, users could manually enter any hostname or IP address to connect.

Starting with 4.4.0, there is now also `$cfg['ArbitraryServerRegexp']` which can be used to restrict users to certain hostnames or IP addresses; this way system administrators can allow some arbitrary connections while still prohibiting access to, say, a QA staging server or random public servers. Prior to version 4.4.0, there was no means to use regexp to restrict the arbitrary server.